# Updating multiple records with FormView/UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is it possible to create a form with `FormView` or `UpdateView` that shows and updates all records from a table?

Basically i have table with 100 records, i want to list in one form, where each record has a radiobutton that can either be True or False. When the radiobutton has been checked the submission should update all records.

The only way that i see it right now is doing a `TemplateView` and basically building everything from scratch and iterating through the list and updating it when the form has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model formsets are what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function

Comment: Can you give an example?